# looped execution of code snippet even when the application is in background?

Tags: java, android

I am developing a app in android ....
which need a code snippet to be executed in a loop...
i thought of using threads and handler..
i need some assistance on that...

and is there any other optimistic way of doing it...

consider it like an alarm clock, where the program continually checks for the alarm time with the mobile time ... i need to implement a concept similar to this ...

pls help me out guys ... Thanks :) :)

Comment: If your going to do this please please be aware that if you run code continually you can dramatically affect battery life!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a Service... and your app will use it.. like this, even if your app is garbaged, your service can still run.

Comment: and probably should have this code as a thread in the service

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make something like an alarm clock where something will happen at a specific time then you want to be using the built in [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). It will let you pass an [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) to it so that your program runs at the specific time